# TypeError with urlopen()

Tags: python

I am a bit confused with using Request, urlopen and JSONDecoder().decode().

Currently I have:

```
hdr = {'User-agent' : 'anything'}  # header, User-agent header describes my web browser
```

I am assuming that the server uses this to determine which browsers are acceptable? Not sure

my url is:

```
url = 'http://wwww.reddit.com/r/aww.json'
```

I set a req variable

```
req = Request(url,hdr)  #request to access the url with header
json = urlopen(req).read()   # read json page
```

I tried using urlopen in terminal and I get this error:

```
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not dict # This has to do with me header?

data = JSONDecoder().decode(json)   # translate json data so I can parse through it with regular python functions?
```

I'm not really sure why I get the `TypeError`

Comment: hdr is a `dict` and `Request` is expecting a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [`Request`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request), you can see that the constructor signature is actually `Request(url, data=None, headers={}, …)`. So the second parameter, the one after the URL, is the *data* you are sending with the request. But if you want to set the headers instead, you will have to specify the `headers` parameter.

You can do this in two different ways. Either you pass `None` as the data parameter:

```
Request(url, None, hdr)
```

But, well, this requires you to pass the `data` parameter explicitely and you have to make sure that you pass the default value to not cause any unwanted effects. So instead, you can tell Python to *explicitely* pass the `header` parameter instead, without specifying `data`:

```
Request(url, headers=hdr)
```

Comment: I tried using `header=hdr` but I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'` The `None` method ran without errors. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: @Liondancer Oops, apparently I don’t follow my own advice and don’t read the signature in the documentation well enough :D It should be `headers=hdr` (plural headers, not header).